# R - Remove Territories in shape file and aggregate to higher NUTS level

Tags: r, r-sf, tmap

I am trying to create an EU shapefile. I want to remove all the oversea territories and then plot country borders. I downloaded NUTS1 Level Shapefiles from Eurostat (http://gisco-services.ec.europa.eu/distribution/v2/countries/download/ref-countries-2020-01m.shp.zip) using "NUTS_RG_01M_2021_3035_LEVL_1.shp" and removed the oversea territories (Spain, France, Portugal etc). Now I essentially want to aggregate back to NUTS0 Level, to only plot the outer country borders. Is this possible? I tried st_union but this is aggregating onto the outer EU-border, removing all borders.

So far my code is as follows:

```
#read shapefile
EU.sf <- st_read("/ref-nuts-2021-01m.shp/NUTS_RG_01M_2021_3035_LEVL_1.shp/NUTS_RG_01M_2021_3035_LEVL_1.shp")

#plot without oversea territories 
EUmap <- tm_shape(st_union(subset(EU.sf, 
                  NUTS_ID != "FRY" &
                    NUTS_ID != "PT2" &
                    NUTS_ID != "PT3" &
                    NUTS_ID != "ES7" &
                    CNTR_CODE != "TR"
                  ))) +
  tm_borders()
```

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like `aggregate()` from `sf` should do this, but you'll need to have both the NUTS0 and NUTS1 codes defined for each unit.  Otherwise, if you've got two different shape files, one for NUTS0 and one for NUTS1, you could use `st_overlaps()` to find the NUTS1 polygons that overlaps the NUTS0 polygons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on your expected outcome, but it looks like the `CNTR_CODE` variable in the NUTS1 file contains country codes that are equivalent to the NUTS0 boundaries. If that is the case, you can use `dplyr::count()` to combine all the polygons that have the same `CNTR_CODE` from the NUTS1 file.

Just a note, in this example, I downloaded a geojson of the boundaries from here: https://gisco-services.ec.europa.eu/distribution/v1/nuts-2021.html

```r
library(sf)
library(tidyverse)

tmp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://gisco-services.ec.europa.eu/distribution/v2/nuts/geojson/NUTS_RG_01M_2021_3035_LEVL_1.geojson", tmp)
nuts1 <- read_sf(tmp)

nuts_agg <- nuts1 %>% 
  filter(!NUTS_ID %in% c("FRY", "PT2", "PT3", "ES7") & CNTR_CODE != "TR") %>% 
  count(CNTR_CODE)

nuts_agg %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf()
```

[image]